# Dynamic background height when using float elements

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/nUcXQ/

How to get dynamic height on the main (black background) I'm using image so I can't use repeat-y-
Additionally the height has to be 0px if main doesn't have any list elements

Has to work in IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/nUcXQ/1/)

Try removing any height declarations and floating `.main`

```
.main{
    background: black;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't restrict the height to 10px, unless you're trying to do something and I'm just missing it.

```
.main{
    background: black;
    width: 300px;
}

li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

The only other thing you need is a clearfix to stop the floating after the last li.

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

<br class="clearfix">
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUcXQ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work in IE8 - in `.main` remove all `height` references and add `display:inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from main class

```
height:10px;
```

Add this line just after closing ul

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nUcXQ/3/